# Huawei honor 4x - merge/link contacts

Tags: huawei

I bought Huawei honor 4x a couple of weeks ago and I've been banging my head on how to merge/link contacts. I got 400 odd contacts from google and facebook (some are same contacts with different names). I am trying to manually link some contacts. I choose the contact -> edit. I am not able to find the link/merge contact option. I have now ended up with multiple entries and I am not able to merge them.
Where the is the link/merge option?? I have tried a lot and am frustrated.

Comment: Do you have a google account? Add your contacts to gmail, and try the merge in the gmail contact list. Much easier on the computer than on the phone. I am not sure how facebook contacts are managed, so try with one or two contacts first, and post results here.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to default **Contacts** app, I found these apps namely [Merge +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android.merger) and [Simpler Contacts & Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simpler.contacts)
which allows merging duplicate phone contacts.

---

#### About Merge +

> Merge+ helps you easily find & merge duplicate contacts.
>   With Merge+, you can join duplicate contacts in your Android phone & Tablet with only three clicks:
>
> 1. LAUNCH Merge+ to find duplicate contacts
> 2. REVIEW merge suggestions and mark who to merge
> 3. MERGE your selected duplicate contacts

#### About Simpler Contacts & Dialer

> With Simpler you can easily merge all your duplicate contacts and quickly find the contacts your need.
>
> MAIN FEATURES
>
> - Simply merge all duplicate contacts!
> - Never lose your contacts again with Simpler Backup!
> - T9 Dialer - quickly search by name & numbers
> - Quickly call to your frequently used contacts
> - Clean & intuitive design - Android Lollipop L Style
>
> SIMPLY MERGE DUPLICATE CONTACTS
>
> - Merge all duplicate contacts with one tap!
> - Find & merge contacts with similar names.
> - Find & Merge contacts with duplicate phone or email.